# How to use service identies to use rest api in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps provides a [RestApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and a [CLI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension) to automate some tasks. For authentication, you can use a PAT, and the user linked to the PAT needs to have the appropriate permissions.

I do not want to use my personal account to create those PATs, due to various reasons:
- I do not want to show up as the person doing all those changes (commiting, changing workitems, ...) This would make history very hard to read.
- I would need to take care of the token lifetime and renew the tokens.
- Sometimes I need a second user, e.g. to approve a PR that has been created automatically (branch policies enforce a reviewer that must not be the person creating the PR)

How can I use managed identities or service accounts (or generic users) to create those PATS?

I know I can use service endpoints to connect TO other services, but how can I create an *incoming* service hook?

Comment: Great question.  I'm wondering the same.